# O que significa estar sublinhado este trecho do código?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

Estou tentando usar um searchview junto com o listview do meu projeto, mas não estou conseguindo, pois onde eu vou setar o adapter do lisview dentro do metodo onQueryTextChange, o mesmo aparece sublinhado e não esta funcionando corretamento como deveria.

O que significa estar sublinhado ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não está a funcionar como devia não é por essa razão.

Neste caso, o sublinhado do nome da variável indica que é uma variável local *final* declarada fora da classe anónima onde está a ser usada.

Comment: Isto não seria mais um comentário que uma resposta?!

Comment: @JorgeB. Porquê? Por ser curta? Esta é a resposta à pergunta. Não tenho culpa que seja apenas isto que há para dizer.:)

Comment: ramaral não, nada a ver com ser curta. Eu acho é que a pergunta devia estar fechada.

Comment: @JorgeB. Compreendo, mas tenho dúvidas se há razão para ser fechada.

Comment: @ramaral - Entendido. Obrigado.